# Issue receiving event on prototype bean when used through interface?

Tags: java, spring

A little bit new with spring. When I instantiate a bean via interface, it doesn't seem to get events, if however, I use actual class implementing the interface, then the event is received. Why is this? Code below.

```
package javabeans.di;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextStartedEvent;


public class HelloWorldImpl  implements HelloWorld,  ApplicationListener<ContextStartedEvent> {

    private String msg;

    public HelloWorldImpl(String s){
        msg = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void printHelloWorld() {

        System.out.println("Hello : " + msg);
    }


    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextStartedEvent event) {
          System.out.println("ContextStartedEvent Received");
    }
}
```

Here is the calling code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     ConfigurableApplicationContext  ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(HelloWorldConfig.class);

     // Let us raise a start event.
    ctx.start();           

    HelloWorld obj = (HelloWorld) ctx.getBean("helloWorld");        
    obj.printHelloWorld();

    ctx.stop();
}
```

Config class:

```
@Configuration
public class HelloWorldConfig {

   @Bean 
   @Scope("prototype")
   public HelloWorld helloWorld(){
      return new HelloWorldImpl("Hello java beans");
   }



}
```

The interface:

```
package javabeans.di;

public interface HelloWorld {

    void printHelloWorld();

}
```

*"ContextStartedEvent Received"* never gets shown if the bean has a prototype scope.

**NOTE**: If I change *return type* of bean method to `HelloWorldImpl` in the config class, and also change `HelloWorld` to `HelloWorldImpl` inside main (two occurrences - basically on the line where I call `getBean`), then *this works* also with prototype beans. 
Why would that be? Additionally if I create two instances of `HelloWorldImpl` in main, in a manner described in this paragraph, still the event is received only once (but that might be separate issue).

Comment: ... The bean doesn't exist when the context starts, so why would it receive a context start event?

Comment: @DaveNewton That doesn't seem to be an issue, you can see my update, it seems to have with using interfaces, but I fail to see why?

Comment: The error is that you are receiving a start event when using the implementation class instead of the interface. You shouldn't be receiving the event, since prototype beans are created by Spring lazily (in this case, when you call `getBean()`)

Comment: You don't even receive the _start_ event? when you do ctx.start()??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using java based configuration what happens is very early in the process the `@Configuration` classes are read with ASM (they aren't loaded through a class loader yet). Based on that read bytecode Spring creates the bean definitions and proxy based classes.

A `@Bean` method (regardless where it is) is basically the same as a [`FactoryBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html). It acts more or less in the same way. When the meta data is created  it does so by inspecting the *method signature* and using the return type to create a factory. This return type is basically used for the [`getObjectType`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html#getObjectType--) method of a `FactoryBean`. And this the result of that method is used to determine what the bean supports.

Now when return `HelloWorld` as a type you get a factory creating beans of that type. When using `HelloWorldImpl` you will get a factory creating beans of that type. The first doesn't contain the `ApplicationListener` interface and as such is ignored by spring, the second however does (it is detected at that point of generating the (auto) configuration meta data).

So when using `@Configuration` with `@Bean` it is important to be as specific as possible about the return type.

Comment: I will accept this answer but give bounty to currently accepted answer if you don't mind. Both answers contain basically same info, yours is just more elaborate and better written.

Comment: Not entirely the other one is just a guess and imho lacks the actual information. But it is for you to decide :).

Comment: I already gave bounty, he has fewer rep to, and essentially both were answers in correct direction. I also upvoted your answer. ps. you seem to have rep points anyway :)

Comment: I don't really care for the rep, just try to help people and hopefully teach them something along the way. :)

Answer (score 3):

Isn't this because the interface itself doesn't have the listening method?
Shouldn't you

```
package javabeans.di;

public interface HelloWorld extends ApplicationListener<ContextStartedEvent>{

    void printHelloWorld();
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextStartedEvent event);

}
```

And then `@Override` in the implementing class?

Answer (score 2):

This is just a guess, but the ApplicationListener interface is only available for the concrete implementation class HelloWorldImpl. Thus when spring creates the helloWorld bean it creates a type HelloWorld which does not have the ApplicationListener interface and thus the event will not be propagated to this bean.

Let the HelloWorld interface extend ApplicationListener and you should receive an event.

Comment: this seems a fair guess, I had similar guess, and I naively thought to make HelloWorld implement ApplicationListener interface, which is not possible.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava How is that not possible?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Well interface can't implement another interface

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava Use the `extends` keyword

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner damn, beat me to it by 13 seconds

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Yes I noted this suggestion, I said I mistakenly was trying to use implements keyword.

Comment: This answer is not entirely correct. What happens is when the `@Bean` method is transformed into a factory method (which it actually is) based on the return type of the method signature it decided what to do. It inspects the method signature at that point NOT the actual bean instance at runtime. Hence that is why it works when you have `HelloWorldImpl` as a return type as opposed to `HelloWorld` as a return type.